# How's a simple way to download a bunch of URLs into S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of URLs to some files I want in S3 (about 500), each are around 80-100mb. I want to get them into S3 while staying within the the free limits for everything other than S3.

What's the best way to approach this? I've put the URL's in a .txt in S3 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is:

- Make an **Excel spreadsheet** of the filenames
- Create a **formula** that creates a copy command with the filename (see below)
- **Launch an Amazon EC2 Linux instance** in the same region as the bucket. The `t2.micro` is included in the free tier, but has relatively small network bandwidth. I'd splurge on a `t2.large`, but launch it as a Spot instance and you'll only pay a few cents. It depends whether you want to save time or save a few cents.
- Connect to the EC2 instance and **paste** the commands from Excel
- When finished, **terminate** the EC2 instance (it is charged per second)

The command you'd want in Excel is:

```
wget <URL>; aws s3 cp <filename> s3://my-bucket/<filename>; rm <filename>;
```

When launching the EC2 instance, also assign it an IAM Role that has permissions to access the S3 bucket.

Test is out by copying the first few files, one at a time. If that looks good, paste larger batches of 100 at a time. It might seem primitive, but it's a fast way to copy that many files. I'd do it differently if it was 1000+ files.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Had to play around with the URLs to get the filenames but luckily they were closely linked!